# Why didn't they kill Frankenstein's monster right away?

Tags: frankensteins-monster, frankenstein-1931

In the 1931 film [*Frankenstein*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankenstein_(1931_film)), at one point Dr. Waldman injected tranquilizer into the monster causing it to pass out. Dr. Waldman then planned on dissecting the monster and noted that he had to keep giving him stronger and stronger sedatives.

Why didn't they kill the monster before starting? Or at least restrain him?

They already saw he was dangerous and Dr. Waldman had said he should be shot like any savage.

Answer (score -1):

Serious answer? That would have precluded the rest of the movie. Waldman promised Henry the Monster would be taken care of, humanely I believe was his intent. He just underestimated how fast the Monster's resistance to being knocked out would build up.

Comment: This seems like pure guesswork.